# Calculate Speed up

Tags: performance, cpu-architecture

This question is related Computer Organization and Architecture. i would truly appreciate some assistance

Processor A has a clock speed of 1 GHz, and takes 1 cycle for integer operations, 2 cycles for memory operations, and 4 cycles for floating point operations. Empirical data shows that programs run on Processor A typically are composed of 35% floating point operations, 30% memory operations; and 35% integer operations. 
However you wish to design a new processor, Processor B, which is an improvement on Processor A. Processor B will run the same programs as Processor A. To complete your design, you are faced with two options for improving performance:

1. Increase the clock speed to 1.2 GHz, but memory operations take 3 cycles
2. Decrease the clock speed to 900 MHz, but floating point operations only take 3 cycles

Compute the speedup for both options and decide the option Processor B should take.

i have tried finding the Execution time for Processors A and B by using ICxCPIxCT. I used MIPS (Clock rate/CPIx10^6) as the IC in all cases. When i was finished with everything, the Processor B(1) was deemed the most efficient since it had the lowest CPU time(940.3x10^-9) but i'm not sure if my method was correct.

Comment: Homework assignment?

Comment: yes, take home assignment

Comment: @Chev, you are on the right path. There are different ways to solve this, but your conclusion is right.

Comment: I made a quick calculation and got a different result (b2 being marginally faster). You should post the formula that you used to determine relative performance.

Comment: i actually miscalculated with my reading for B(1). Now i'm really doubting my approach since readings for Procs B1 and B2 were almost identical and both were very close to Proc A.

Comment: Proc A: CPI  = 0.35(1) + 0.3(2) + 0.35(4) =2.35
... MIPS = clock rate/CPI x 10^6
 1 GHz = 1000 MHz
..Therefore,
MIPS = 1000 x 106/2.35 x 10^6
 = 425.3
....
Execution Time = 425.3 x 2.35 x 1 x 10^-9
        = 999.5 x 10^-9

Comment: Proc B1..CPI  = 0.35(1) + 0.3(3) + 0.35(4) =2.65

..MIPS = 1200 x 10^6/2.65 x 10^6
 = 452.8

Execution Time = 452.8 x 2.65 x 1/1.2 x 10^-9
        = 999.9 x 10^-9

Comment: Proc B2..CPI = 0.35(1) + 0.3(2) + 0.35(3) =2 ..MIPS = 900 x 10^6/2 x 10^6 = 450.. Execution Time = 450 x 2.65 x 1/0.9 x 10^-9 = 1000 x 10^-9

Comment: Stupid me, I miscalculated myself. B1 is indeed faster, about 6.4% speedup.

Comment: Just FYI, this is an totally over-simplified model of execution.  All but the simplest real CPUs are pipelined so multi-cycle operations can overlap with each other, if there's no data dependency.  (This makes branching and branch-prediction are a huge deal.  But if you fully execute an instruction before even looking at the next instruction, like this non-pipelined CPU, then sure I guess you can count branches as integer operations...)  Anything with an FPU or running at anywhere near 1GHz will be pipelined because the gains in IPC are huge. TL:DR: this is mostly a math word problem, not real

Comment: that sounds like your B1 CPU Time was 940.3x10^-9 ... thats what i got initial but for some reason i'm getting something else now lol

Comment: Hi Peter, yes u are right about the oversimplification. pipeline is not involved with this particular question. that's covered under another section

Comment: Given that there's likely an exponential relationship between clock frequency and power consumption; I'd choose option 2 and market the CPU as a more power efficient CPU for scientific workloads; then (later) I'd put multiple cores on a die and still be within the original package TDP limits. The empirical data isn't very relevant (as soon as people/compilers start optimizing code for Processor B any empirical data from Processor A will be wrong) and is a bad predictor of marketing strategies.